# cant get my dialog element to show from calling a function

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

my dialog element which is a confirmation modal that is supposed to pop up after a successful api call in this function.

```
const addModal = useRef<HTMLDialogElement>(null);
const addConfirm = addModal.current!;

async function handleAddProduct(item: typeof newItem) {
    setShopLoading(true);

    try {
      const response = await privateReq.post("/items", item);
      addConfirm.showModal(); 
      //more codes ...
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error):
    } finally {
      setShopLoading(false);
    }
  }

    <section>
      <form onSubmit={(e) => (e.preventDefault(), handleAddProduct(newItem))}>
        //input here...
      </form>

      <dialog ref={addModal}>
        <h1>Item added successfully</h1>
        <button
          onClick={(e) => (
            e.preventDefault(), addConfirm.close(), setNewItem(initInput)
          )}
        >
          Add more
        </button>
        //more dialog ...
      </dialog>
    </section>
```

I get this error when i run this function

`Uncaught DOMException: HTMLDialogElement.showModal: Dialog element is not connected`

I tried to just test it without the api call and it works as intended

```
async function handleAddProduct(item: typeof newItem) {
 
addConfirm.showModal(); 
 return    //exits the function to test if modal is working

    setShopLoading(true);
    try {
      const response = await privateReq.post("/items", item);
            setShopItems(response.data?.updatedList);
      addedId.current = response.data?.added?.item_id;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error):
    } finally {
      setShopLoading(false);
    }
  }
```

I also tried to bind the modal to a state and useeffect to make sure its not null when showModal() is called but it didnt change anything

Comment: Can't say I've seen the comma operator used like this, can you confirm that it's not messing anything up? With that many expressions why not separate the callback to another method? It would be easier to debug what's happening

Comment: can confirm it is working when i remove the api call from the function, the showmodal is working how i intend it to. sorry about that, didnt want to make another function with just prevent default and the actual function so i usually do this.

Comment: @Phix Please consider submitting an answer that details this issue in case another user tries to use the comma operator in a similar way.